# ImportError: cannot import name cpg

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy

I have this project that I find on the `http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-cherrypy/?ca=dgr-lnxw01CherryPy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import cpg

class Application:
    @cpg.expose
    def hello(self, what='Hello', who='world'):
        return '%s, %s!' % (what, who)
cpg.root = Application()
cpg.server.start()
```

But I think the site is old and I have the python's version is  2.7.3.

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello4.py", line 3, in <module>
from cherrypy import cpg
ImportError: cannot import name cpg
```

For install the program 's cherrypy `http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/xenwebmanager/wiki/GettingStarted`

what has changed with the new version of python?

How to change for using the project for python 2.7.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cherrypy.cpg` was removed in 2.1](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/wiki/UpgradeTo21).  You need to find some docs more recent than 2005.

Comment: How to change for python 2.7.3?

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani the Python version doesn't matter. As for changes required, did you try to read the upgrade guide in my link?

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani really? https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/wiki/UpgradeTo21 then